# How to get a specific value from a two dimensional arrays

Tags: php, sql, opencart

I am creating a module in open cart. In my model i have query which i save it like this.

```
$zone_id=array();
$zone_id=$this->db->query("SELECT geo_zone_id FROM  `oc_geo_zone` WHERE name= (  SELECT name FROM  `oc_zone`  WHERE zone_id = (  SELECT shipping_zone_id  FROM  `oc_order` WHERE order_id = '".$order_id."' ) ) ");
```

I can not use print_r() here so i am using log object for debugging.
when i write this

```
$this->log->write($zone_id);
```

i get this result.

```
[num_rows] => 1
[row] => Array
    (
        [geo_zone_id] => 6
    )

[rows] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [geo_zone_id] => 6
            )

    )
```

How can i fetch the value 6 from this zone_id array i tried this but got nothing.

```
 $this->log->write($zone_id[0]['geo_zone_id']);
```

Comment: `$zone_id['rows'][0]['geo_zone_id']`

Comment: @splash58 tried what u said but got nothing plain log file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one

```
$result = $zone_id->row['geo_zone_id'];

echo $result;
```

Opencart query will always returns output in object.

Comment: pERFECT CAN U PLEASE explain why its giving me result in row and rows array not single array lie in print_r()?

Comment: its by default function of OC so in single query you can get multiple things, single row, all rows & no of rows.